# Ран-тайм ошибка с методом Add объекта ListRows, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Всем доброго времени суток. Надеюсь на помощь знающих. Ситуация простецкая, буду сильно благодарен за ваше уделенное внимание.
Чтобы сэкономить ваше время я убрал всё лишнее и упростил свою программу до простейших вещей - в моём проекте 2 книги (первая - База данных.xlsx, вторая Проект.xlsm). В базе данных содержится лишь один лист и одна таблица в которой записаны имена и возраст сотрудников.

Во второй книге у меня уже два листа. На первом листе расположена кнопка "Открыть первое меню".
При нажатии на эту кнопку появляется простейшая юзер-форма в которой есть кнопка на еще одно меню. Второе меню чуть-чуть сложнее. (фото - второе меню.jpg) Оно представляет из себя два листбокса и три кнопки.

Первый листбокс автоматически (при инициализации формы) загружается именами и возрастом, например сотрудников, из базы данных (моя первая книга). При нажатии на кнопку со стрелкой вниз имя и возраст человека перетаскиваются в листбокс "Выбранные имена".
Насколько мне известно программно задать названия колонок в листбоксе мы не можем. Он автоматически их берёт из шапки. Для этого и нужен второй лист книги "Проект.xlsm". На этом втором листе расположена таблица, в которую при нажатии на кнопку со стрелкой вниз помещается выделенный элемент листбокса (имя и возраст).

Далее для листбокса "Выбранные имена" я обновляю RowSource новым dataBodyRange.address таблицы на втором листе. Благодаря чему во втором листбоксе также присутствуют заголовки столбцов.
Стрелка вверх служит для удаления элементов из листбокса выбранных имён и удаления элемента из таблицы второго листа книги Проект.xlsm
Кнопка отмена полностью очищает таблицу второго листа и закрывает форму.

Всё это прекрасно работает до тех пор, пока не нажать несколько раз на кнопку со стрелкой вниз. Из ран-тайма вылетает ошибка
Method 'Add' of object 'ListRows' failed. Эксель виснет и закрывается. И вылетает эта ошибка когда захочет. Например в данном случае она вылетела на третий раз нажатия на кнопку со стрелкой вниз. Иногда это может быть на раз 5, 6.
А теперь самое интересное. Методом проб и ошибок я выяснил, что если добавить кнопку с панели "Разработчик" - "Вставить" - "Кнопка" именно на второй лист моей книги "Проект.xlsm" (обычную пустышку, без макроса) проблема почему-то исчезает! Занавес!
Прошу помочь разобраться в данной проблеме.

[image: второе меню]
[image: ошибка ран-тайма]

Comment: Где код лебовски?

Comment: Лебовски "Excel cannot handle the Table Reference for the ListBox RowSource when the table is resized."

Comment: Это весь код вашего скрипта? тогда у меня для вас плохие новости.....

Comment: >>*Чтобы сэкономить ваше время* - для этого надо показать этот пример, чтобы можно было пощупать код вживую.